# How to move to another function if a condition is met?

Tags: python, function

I'm making a student portal and one of the features is that you select a number and depending on the number you select it takes you to that page (all work is done in the terminal).
I have only created the first function for student registration but when I press option 1 it doesn't redirect you to the student registration function which was made (filling in your info)??

```
#Need to be able to pick the option you want to be redirected to.
def Options():
    print("1) Student Registration \n2) Module selection and verification \n3) Student top-up \n4) Shopping (printing and food) \n5) Checking Balance \n6) Edit Information \n7) Reporting")
    options = int(input("Type the number of the option you would like to proceed to: "))
    
    if options == 1:
        student_registration()
        
    elif options == 2:
        module_selection_and_verification()
        
    elif options == 3:
        student_account_top_up()
        
    elif options == 4:
        shopping()
        
    elif options == 5:
        checking_balance()
        
    elif options == 6:
        edit_information()
        
    elif options == 7:
        reporting()
        
    else:
        print("Input out of range. Please try again.")
        Options()
        
Options()

#Option 1: Student Registration
def student_registration():
    print("Welcome to the registration portal.")

    
    student_first_name = str(input("Enter your first name: "))
    student_last_name = str(input("Enter your last name: "))
    student_age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    student_contact_number = int(input("Provide a contact number: "))
    student_email = str(input("Enter your email address: "))
    student_password = (input("Create a password: "))
```

I just started functions and now have a project on them, not sure how to relate back to them if they are internal and how to call variables from outside the function.

Comment: You almost certainly do not want recursion for this. Build a dictionary of the options with references to their functions then it's a simple look-up

Comment: You don't need to use `str()` when you call `input()`. It always returns a string.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what exactly happens when you run the code.

Comment: You need to define `student_registration()` before you call `Options()`. Code is executed in order, so you'll get an error if the function isn't defined before you try to call it.

Comment: You can have function definitions out of order, but the top-level call has to be last.

Answer (score 1):

Define the `student_registration` before the `Options` function. When running "Options", "student_registration" is still not processed by the interpreter.

Ideally, you should have a main function and that should be the only function you call in the outermost scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Options` before `student_registration` is defined.  You can define functions in any order as long as you don't actually try to call one before it is defined.  See:  [Does the order of functions in a Python script matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423786/does-the-order-of-functions-in-a-python-script-matter)

```
#Need to be able to pick the option you want to be redirected to.
def Options():
    print("1) Student Registration \n2) Module selection and verification \n3) Student top-up \n4) Shopping (printing and food) \n5) Checking Balance \n6) Edit Information \n7) Reporting")
    options = int(input("Type the number of the option you would like to proceed to: "))
    
    if options == 1:
        student_registration()
        
    elif options == 2:
        module_selection_and_verification()
        
    elif options == 3:
        student_account_top_up()
        
    elif options == 4:
        shopping()
        
    elif options == 5:
        checking_balance()
        
    elif options == 6:
        edit_information()
        
    elif options == 7:
        reporting()
        
    else:
        print("Input out of range. Please try again.")
        Options()
        
#Option 1: Student Registration
def student_registration():
    print("Welcome to the registration portal.")

    
    student_first_name = str(input("Enter your first name: "))
    student_last_name = str(input("Enter your last name: "))
    student_age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    student_contact_number = int(input("Provide a contact number: "))
    student_email = str(input("Enter your email address: "))
    student_password = (input("Create a password: "))

Options()
```